# Bent paths via relative point from node to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to draw a network flow diagram in tikz, and am having some problems.

Here is what I have so far:
[image: Current diagram]

However I'm having 2 problems with it currently. First of all, for some reason, arrow appear at *both ends* of my lines if I specify an anchor of my source node. If you look carefully at the picture, you can see some arcs have arrows at both ends. All arcs should be point left to right only.

For example `(h1) edge [bend left=15] (1_1)` will give an arrow only at the end, as I expect; however `(h1.east) edge [bend left=15] (1_1)` will put an arrow on both sides.

The second problem is that I need additional arcs that are longer and should avoid the existing arcs and nodes. Like this:

[image: Extra arcs]

Here is my code so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0,0) (h1);

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=blue,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,1.5) (1_1) { 1:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=green, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,0) (2_1) { 2:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=red,   fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,-1.5) (3_1) { 3:1 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (3,0) (h2);

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (4.5,0.75) (4_1) { 4:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (6.0,0.75) (4_2) { 4:2 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=purple, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (4.5,-0.75) (5_1) { 5:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=purple, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (6.0,-0.75) (5_2) { 5:2 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (7.5,0) (h3);

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=teal,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (9.0,0.75) (6_1) { 6:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=teal,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (10.5,0.75) (6_2) { 6:2 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=olive, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (9.75,-0.75) (7_1) { 7:1 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (12,0)   (h4);
    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (13.5,0) (h5);

    \draw [->] (0.333,-2.5) -- (13.3335,-2.5) node [midway, below] {Time};

    \path [line, ->] (h1) edge [bend left=15] (1_1);
    \path [line, ->] (h1) edge (2_1);
    \path [line, ->] (h1) edge [bend right=15] (3_1);
    \path [line, ->] (1_1) edge [bend left=15] (h2);
    \path [line, ->] (2_1) edge (h2);
    \path [line, ->] (3_1) edge [bend right=15] (h2);
    \path [line, ->] (h2.20) edge [bend left=15] (4_1);
    \path [line, ->] (h2.-20) edge [bend right=15] (5_1);
    \path [line, ->] (4_1) -- (4_2);
    \path [line, ->] (5_1) -- (5_2);
    \path [line, ->] (4_2) edge [bend left=15] (h3.160);
    \path [line, ->] (5_2) edge [bend right=15] (h3.200);
    \path [line, ->] (h3) edge [bend left=15] (6_1);
    \path [line, ->] (h3) edge [bend right=15] (7_1);
    \path [line, ->] (6_1) -- (6_2);
    \path [line, ->] (6_2) edge [bend left=15] (h4);
    \path [line, ->] (7_1) edge [bend right=15] (h4);
    \path [line, ->] (h4) -- (h5);

    \path [line, ->] (h2.60) edge [bend left=60] (4_2.north west);
    \path [line, ->] (h2.-60) edge [bend right=60] (5_2.south west);
    \path [line, ->] (4_1.north east) edge [bend left=60] (h3.120);
    \path [line, ->] (5_1.south east) edge [bend right=60] (h3.240);
    \path [line, ->] (h3.0) edge [bend right=15] (6_2.south west);
    \path [line, ->] (6_1.south east) edge [bend right=15] (h4.180);

    \path [line, ->] (4_1) -- (5_2);
    \path [line, ->] (5_1) -- (4_2);

    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (0.2, 2)  -- (2.8, 2)  node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 1};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (3.2, 2)  -- (7.3, 2)  node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 2};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (7.7, 2)  -- (11.8, 2) node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 3};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (12.2, 2) -- (13.3, 2) node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 4};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please tell us how you defined `line`. Make a complete example code starting from `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}` so that it is compilable.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{line}     = [draw, -latex']`. This isn't my code, I don't understand what it does. I got it from here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/

Comment: Use `\path [-latex'] (h1.north) edge [out=90,in=90,bend angle=180,looseness=2](h2.north);` Change `looseness` value as you wish. `\tikzstyle` is wrong. Use `\tikzset{line/.style={-latex'}}` instead. It defines a style for line.

Comment: Ahhh this works but it killed all my other diagrams now that `line` has changed!. Anyway, I can fix it later. It's almost perfect now; but can you tell me why the arrow heads are different on some lines? http://i.imgur.com/HmAgG0g.png

Comment: Because you have used `\path [line, ->]`. Use `\path [line]`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. If you want to make your suggestions answers, I'll accept them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tikzstyle` is deprecated. Use `\tikzset` instead like

```
\tikzset{line/.style={-latex'}}
```

to define a line style. You are also using `\path[line, ->]` which results in modifying the line style. Use `\path[line]` instead. To change the extent of bending you can adjust the `looseness` value with `in` and `out` angles like

```
\path [-latex'] (h1.north) edge [out=90,in=90,bend angle=180,looseness=2](h2.north);
```

Further, the `node`s should have an empty argument `{}`

```
\node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0,0) (h1) {};   %% note the {} at the end
```

which is missing in your code. Putting all these your code becomes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{line/.style={-latex'}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (0,0) (h1) {};

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=blue,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,1.5) (1_1) { 1:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=green, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,0) (2_1) { 2:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=red,   fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (1.5,-1.5) (3_1) { 3:1 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (3,0) (h2) {};

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (4.5,0.75) (4_1) { 4:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (6.0,0.75) (4_2) { 4:2 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=purple, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (4.5,-0.75) (5_1) { 5:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=purple, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (6.0,-0.75) (5_2) { 5:2 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (7.5,0) (h3) {};

    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=teal,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (9.0,0.75) (6_1) { 6:1 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=teal,  fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (10.5,0.75) (6_2) { 6:2 };
    \node [circle, draw, inner sep=0.075cm, fill=olive, fill opacity=0.33, text opacity=1] at (9.75,-0.75) (7_1) { 7:1 };

    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (12,0)   (h4) {};
    \node [pattern=north east lines, circle, draw, inner sep=0.25cm] at (13.5,0) (h5) {};

    \draw [line] (0.333,-2.5) -- (13.3335,-2.5) node [midway, below] {Time};

    \path [line] (h1) edge [bend left=15] (1_1);
    \path [line] (h1) edge (2_1);
    \path [line] (h1) edge [bend right=15] (3_1);
    \path [line] (1_1) edge [bend left=15] (h2);
    \path [line] (2_1) edge (h2);
    \path [line] (3_1) edge [bend right=15] (h2);
    \path [line] (h2.20) edge [bend left=15] (4_1);
    \path [line] (h2.-20) edge [bend right=15] (5_1);
    \path [line] (4_1) -- (4_2);
    \path [line] (5_1) -- (5_2);
    \path [line] (4_2) edge [bend left=15] (h3.160);
    \path [line] (5_2) edge [bend right=15] (h3.200);
    \path [line] (h3) edge [bend left=15] (6_1);
    \path [line] (h3) edge [bend right=15] (7_1);
    \path [line] (6_1) -- (6_2);
    \path [line] (6_2) edge [bend left=15] (h4);
    \path [line] (7_1) edge [bend right=15] (h4);
    \path [line] (h4) -- (h5);

    \path [line] (h2.60) edge [bend left=60] (4_2.north west);
    \path [line] (h2.-60) edge [bend right=60] (5_2.south west);
    \path [line] (4_1.north east) edge [bend left=60] (h3.120);
    \path [line] (5_1.south east) edge [bend right=60] (h3.240);
    \path [line] (h3.0) edge [bend right=15] (6_2.south west);
    \path [line] (6_1.south east) edge [bend right=15] (h4.180);

    \path [line] (4_1) -- (5_2);
    \path [line] (5_1) -- (4_2);

    %% lines with more bend
    \path [line] (h1.north) edge [out=90,in=90,bend angle=180,looseness=2](h2.north);
    \path [line] (h2.south) edge [out=270,in=270,bend angle=180,looseness=1.3](h3.south);
    \path [line] (h3.70) edge [controls=+(80:2) and +(100:2)](h4.120);    %% just to show another way
    \path [line] (h4.east) edge (h5.west);

    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (0.2, 2)  -- (2.8, 2)  node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 1};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (3.2, 2)  -- (7.3, 2)  node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 2};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (7.7, 2)  -- (11.8, 2) node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 3};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=8pt, raise=8pt}] (12.2, 2) -- (13.3, 2) node [midway, above, yshift=0.5cm] {Day 4};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]